# Will extending the size of a varchar field in MySQL affect the data thats inside it?

Tags: mysql, database-design, varchar

I am going to be extending the column from VARCHAR(350) to VARCHAR(800) - will affect any of the strings that are inside the column already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding, no.

Shrinking, yes.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will only affect new data inserted/updated after you've made the change by allowing you to change or add new values up to the new length

Answer (score 0):

No you're fine with that